# How do I trim the text and add Ellipsis (...) while using drawInRect: on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, nsstring, drawrect

I've create a subview and implementing the drawRect: method for custom drawing. How do I achieve a behavior similar to that of a UILabel which automatically adds the Ellipsis (...) if the text is too long to fit in its frame.

Here is the code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]};
    [self.sampleText drawInRect:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, self.frame.size.width - 20.0f, self.frame.size.height - 20.0f) withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

If the sampleText is long then it just gets clipped to fit within the specified rect.
How do I add the '...' appropriately?

Comment: Why don't you use a label?

Comment: are you creating custom label by yourself?

Comment: @Wain - There are many images and strings in the view so I want to use custom drawing

Comment: @anum90 - I'm creating a custom view.

Comment: If it is so, simply set: `label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use one of the methods like `drawInRect:withAttributes:` and use the attributed string attributes to set the line truncation style.

---

Try:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *ps = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[ps setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[attributes setObject:ps forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
```

Comment: What attribute should I set?

Comment: By setting paragraph style with the `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` line break mode you will get only single truncated line of text. If you need to show multiple lines with truncation you should use `drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:` with the proper attributes. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40950193/2797141) for details.